# HTML 5 fallback not working. Why?

Tags: internet-explorer, html, html5-video

I am working on a project based on HTML5, I am required to support legacy browsers such as IE 6. I have writtedn following code after reading some tutorials (special thanks to diveintohtml.com), but the code doesnt seems working. Neither audio nor video is working in Internet explorer... can anyone explain why?

```
<audio controls="controls" preload="true">                
  <source src="india.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />
  <object height="40" width="60" classid="clsid:22D6F312-B0F6-11D0-94AB-0080C74C7E95">
    <param name="AutoStart" value="1" />
    <param name="FileName" value="india.mp3" />
    <param name="preLoad" value="true"/>
  </object>
</audio> <br/> <br/>
<video controls="controls" preload="true" autoplay="true">                
  <source src="emptiness.mp4" autoplay="true">
  <source src="billyBrowsers.ogg" autoplay="true">
  <object data="emptiness.flv" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="400" height="350">
    <param value="emptiness.flv" name="movie"/>
  </object>
  <embed src ="emptiness.flv?file=emptiness.flv" width="800" height="600" allowfullscreen="true" />
</video>
```

thanks in advance... sorry for not formatting the question... actually I dont know how to do that..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to implement html5 features in legacy browsers, you are going to need a major HTML5 'shim', such as [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/).

And if you have to get audio and video working in IE6 (ouch) you're going to have to fallback to Flash - check [Video for Everybody](http://camendesign.com/code/video_for_everybody) by Kroc Camen.